# Get all submissions from a subreddit without 'submissions'

Tags: python, api, reddit, praw

Is there any way to get all submissions from a subreddit without using the function submissions() from PRAW? With submissions i was able to search all submission from a given subreddit between two timestamps. But now the Reddit API was updated and searching between two timestamps is no longer available.

For me it is not important to search between two different timestamps, i just need all submission from a given subreddit. So is there anything else i can do?

Answer (score 0):

> not important to search between two different timestamps, i just need all submission from a given subreddit.

In that case, `praw.models.Subreddit` is exactly what you want to use.

```
for submission in reddit.subreddit('all').hot(limit=25):
    print(submission.title)
```

There's further information in the documentation: 
https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/subreddit.html#subreddit